# Filtering a data structure using regex predicates

Tags: regex, clojure, clojurescript

Assume we have a data-structure like this:

```
(def data
     (atom [{:id 1 :first-name "John1" :last-name "Dow1" :age 14}
            {:id 2 :first-name "John2" :last-name "Dow2" :age 54}
            {:id 3 :first-name "John3" :last-name "Dow3" :age 34}
            {:id 4 :first-name "John4" :last-name "Dow4" :age 12}
            {:id 5 :first-name "John5" :last-name "Dow5" :age 24}]))
```

I want to filter it by specific keys using regex in predicates, so I ended up with this function which works fine, but I guess code is ugly and duplicated. How can I get rid of code duplication?

```
(defn my-filter [str-input]
  (let [firstname (filter #(re-find (->> (str str-input)
                                         (upper-case)
                                         (re-pattern))
                                    (upper-case (:first-name %)))
                     @data)
        lastname (filter #(re-find (->> (str str-input)
                                        (upper-case)
                                        (re-pattern))
                                   (upper-case (:last-name %)))
                    @data)
        age (filter #(re-find (->> (str str-input)
                                   (upper-case)
                                   (re-pattern))
                              (upper-case (:age %)))
               @data)]
    (if-not (empty? firstname)
      firstname
      (if-not (empty? lastname)
        lastname
        (if-not (empty? age)
          age)))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up, notice that you're creating 3 `let`ed names by using exactly the same expression but replacing one key lookup function. This is a prime candidate for deduplication by making a local function.

```
(defn my-filter [str-input]
  (let [seek (fn [k](filter #(re-find (->> (str str-input)
                                         (upper-case)
                                         (re-pattern))
                                    (upper-case (k %)))
                     @data))
         firstname (seek :first-name)
        lastname (seek :last-name)
        age (seek :age)]
    (if-not (empty? firstname)
      firstname
      (if-not (empty? lastname)
        lastname
        (if-not (empty? age)
          age)))))
```

Next we can notice that the remainder is just doing the same "return this if it's not empty" logic with each of the three keys in sequence. [`some`](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/some) returns the first non-falsy result of a function on a sequence so by adding a `seq` to the `seek` function we can turn empty `filter` sequences into `nil`s we can combine the two and get the logic we want. I used `letfn` this time because we're only `let`ing fns, might as well.

```
(defn my-filter [str-input]
  (letfn[(seek [k]
               (seq (filter #(re-find (->> (str str-input)
                                         (upper-case)
                                         (re-pattern))
                                    (upper-case (k %)))
                     @data)))]
    (some seek [:first-name :last-name :age])))
```

Comment: Should be `seq`, not `not-empty`. `seq` is for general sequence handling; `not-empty` is only needed for non-sequence collection types where you need to preserve the original input's type while also testing it for emptiness. Also, `comp` improves things here: `(some (comp seq seek [...]))` But better still, move that `seq` call into `seek`: `(fn [k] (seq (filter ...))) ... (some seek [...])`

Answer (score 0):

I reworked the code a bit to something I thought was easier to parse mentally.  I also printed out some intermediate values to show the processing chain in action:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clojure.test tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]]
  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)
(t/print-versions)

(def data
  [{:id 1 :first-name "John"        :last-name "Dog"            :age 14}
   {:id 2 :first-name "Johnny"      :last-name "Cat"            :age 54}
   {:id 3 :first-name "Joe"         :last-name "Doggy"          :age 34}
   {:id 4 :first-name "Jerry"       :last-name "Gyrfalcon"      :age 12}
   {:id 5 :first-name "Jenkins"     :last-name "TheButler"      :age 24}])

(defn case-insensitive-match [pat-str search-str]
  (re-find (re-pattern (str "(?i)" pat-str)) search-str)) ; pattern like #"(?i)xyz" => case-insensitive search

(defn find-rec [rec-list pat-str field-kw]
  (filter #(case-insensitive-match pat-str (str (get % field-kw))) rec-list))

(defn my-filter [rec-list strpat]
  (let [firstname-matches (find-rec rec-list strpat :first-name)
        lastname-matches  (find-rec rec-list strpat :last-name)
        age-matches       (find-rec rec-list strpat :age)]
    (println "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    (spyx firstname-matches)
    (spyx lastname-matches)
    (spyx age-matches)
    (first (remove empty? [firstname-matches lastname-matches age-matches]))))

(newline) (pprint [:john (my-filter data "john")])
(newline) (pprint [:jo (my-filter data "jo")])
(newline) (pprint [:y (my-filter data "y")])
(newline) (pprint [:og (my-filter data "og")])
(newline) (pprint [:3 (my-filter data "3")])
(newline) (pprint [:7 (my-filter data "7")])
```

One thing I don't understand is searching by age and treating it like a string instead of a number. Note that `str/upper-case` silently converts a number like `42` into a string `"42"`. Here I forced it to be explicit.

I also used the regular expression pattern like `#"(?i)abc"` which does a case-insensitive search for "abc".

The results are:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
firstname-matches => ({:id 1, :first-name "John", :last-name "Dog", :age 14} {:id 2, :first-name "Johnny", :last-name "Cat", :age 54})
lastname-matches => ()
age-matches => ()
[:john
 ({:id 1, :first-name "John", :last-name "Dog", :age 14}
  {:id 2, :first-name "Johnny", :last-name "Cat", :age 54})]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
firstname-matches => ({:id 1, :first-name "John", :last-name "Dog", :age 14} {:id 2, :first-name "Johnny", :last-name "Cat", :age 54} {:id 3, :first-name "Joe", :last-name "Doggy", :age 34})
lastname-matches => ()
age-matches => ()
[:jo
 ({:id 1, :first-name "John", :last-name "Dog", :age 14}
  {:id 2, :first-name "Johnny", :last-name "Cat", :age 54}
  {:id 3, :first-name "Joe", :last-name "Doggy", :age 34})]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
firstname-matches => ({:id 2, :first-name "Johnny", :last-name "Cat", :age 54} {:id 4, :first-name "Jerry", :last-name "Gyrfalcon", :age 12})
lastname-matches => ({:id 3, :first-name "Joe", :last-name "Doggy", :age 34} {:id 4, :first-name "Jerry", :last-name "Gyrfalcon", :age 12})
age-matches => ()
[:y
 ({:id 2, :first-name "Johnny", :last-name "Cat", :age 54}
  {:id 4, :first-name "Jerry", :last-name "Gyrfalcon", :age 12})]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
firstname-matches => ()
lastname-matches => ({:id 1, :first-name "John", :last-name "Dog", :age 14} {:id 3, :first-name "Joe", :last-name "Doggy", :age 34})
age-matches => ()
[:og
 ({:id 1, :first-name "John", :last-name "Dog", :age 14}
  {:id 3, :first-name "Joe", :last-name "Doggy", :age 34})]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
firstname-matches => ()
lastname-matches => ()
age-matches => ({:id 3, :first-name "Joe", :last-name "Doggy", :age 34})
[:3 ({:id 3, :first-name "Joe", :last-name "Doggy", :age 34})]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
firstname-matches => ()
lastname-matches => ()
age-matches => ()
[:7 nil]
```